# Define specific cells as a variable in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have the following Dataframe

```
Name    Age    Height    Country
Jack    18      185       AU
Jill    16      159       NZ
Geoff   16      177       US
Tess    15      155       AU
```

I am trying to find a specifc row and then define two variables to use in other calculations.

For example I want to know the height and country of `Geoff`

`name = 'Geoff'`
`h = 177`
`c= US`

Does anyone know the most efficient way of searching and finiding this? Thanks!

Comment: h = df[df['Name']=='Jack']['Height'][0];                   
c = df[df['Name']=='Jack']['Country'][0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use df.loc which freezes the entire row

Example:

```
df.loc[df['Name'] == "Geoff"].Height
```

Comment: Thanks Pat is there then a way of just grabbing the the height on its own? the intersection between `df.loc[df.Name == "Geoff"]` & `df['Height]`?

Comment: No problem! you can just add .Height at the end like so, `df.loc[df.Name == "Geoff"].Height`

Comment: No problem at all, just edited the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can also use df.query

```
df.query('Name == "Geoff"') # To get an entire row based on the filter condition
df.query('Name == "Geoff"').Height # For a specific column value (Height in this case) based on the filter
# or
df.query('Name == "Geoff"')['Height']
```